# Finding All Similar Neighbors in Group - Recursive Function Needed

Tags: vb.net, functional-programming, selection, neighbours

I have a problem where I am sure that there are probably already plenty of efficient solutions out there. For simplification lets assume a grid width cells  of two types of cells, "X" cells and "o" cells.

```
 5 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |X|X|o|X|X|o|o|o|o|o|X
 4 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |o|X|o|o|X|o|o|o|o|o|X
 3 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |o|X|X|X|X|o|o|X|o|o|X
 2 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |X|o|o|X|X|X|X|X|X|o|X
 1 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |X|X|o|o|X|X|X|o|o|o|X 
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 0   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Now one of the "X" cells is being selected.

```
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |X|X|o|X|X|o|o|o|o|o|X
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |o|X|o|o|X|o|o|o|o|o|X
   +-+-+-+-\-/-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |o|X|X|X<*>o|o|X|o|o|X
   +-+-+-+-/-\-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |X|o|o|X|X|X|X|X|X|o|X
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |X|X|o|o|X|X|X|o|o|o|X 
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

What I need to find out are all neighboring "X" cells of the "X" covered area where the selected cell is part of. "X" cells that are not directly connected and separated by an "o" cell from the group are excluded. See illustration below.

```
   +.+.+-+.+.+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   :   :o:   :o|o|o|o|o|X
   +.+ +-+.+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |o: :o|o: :o|o|o|o|o|X
   +-+ +.+.+ +-+-+.+-+-+-+
   |o:       :o|o: :o|o|X
   +-+.+.     .+.+ +.+-+-+
   |X|o|o:           |o|X
   +-+-+-+.+     +.+.+-+-+
   |X|X|o|o:     :o|o|o|X 
   +-+-+-+-+.+.+.+-+-+-+-+
```

Basically its a simple "Fill" function where I need to find the boundaries of that area to fill.
I am sure that there exists even a specific name for this kind of thing. Telling me that would also be appreciated :)

Comment: sounds like a path-finding algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The name of the algorithm you're after is [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). I have a short code sample (in [F#](http://fsharp.org/)) used for a [Pacman clone](http://trelford.com/blog/post/PacTile.aspx).